# VPN Unlimited failure on Lubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: lubuntu, vpn

My Lubuntu 12.04.1 install of VPN Unlimited's client failed about a month after its first use, and their online docs do NOT match the Linux version they provide. I asked for help with these details on 11/06:

"In the past week, your client often won't show me which VPN server I am connecting through and will not allow me to change server locations. Today, I get a complete failure to connect. The DETAILS button shows me VPN Connection is not connected, but when I try to connect, it fails again. Despite what's in your FAQ, there's no instructions provided by the app, and no Manual option. Selecting another server location does not solve the problem.

I downloaded the client from vpnunlimitedapp.com/downloadlinux and reinstalled it using Gdebi after a complete removal with Synaptic Package Manager. Gdebi reported all dependencies were satisfied when it reinstalled. It still fails to connect.
How may I troubleshoot this? What logs may I send you?
Platform: Linux Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit compiler little-endian, App version: 2.3"

On 11/07, they replied: "Hello, JohnI have forwarded your issue to our developers. They will assist as soon as possible. We apologize for any inconvenience."

Which logs and other info could I be looking through to try to solve this on my own?

Once I launch the client, it says it is connected, but I am not able to connect to the Internet with any app, and can't ping out to anywhere.

I can connect to any server only if the VPN Unlimted client is disabled.

There are no log files to be found in /tmp/VPN Unlimited/, nor is there any directory named VPN Unlimited underneath /tmp

*uname -m*  returns the result: **i686**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by the developer's new release.